Kafka offset incrementing after 10 attempts in Spring boot
We have spring boot application to consume the messages from Kafka and put into DB.
We dont want any error handling to be performed in the application if any exception occurs (like DB down etc) instead, kafka should re-try "unlimited" no.of times until the message is acknowledged.
The sample code is like below,
try{

<Processing logic and call DB>

acknowledgement.acknowledge();

}catch(Exceotion e){

acknowledgement.nack(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
throw e;

}

In the config, we have already set "enableAutoCommit" as "false".
The problem is, when there is any exception in the "try" block, its going to "catch" block and re-calling the "consume" method only for "10" times. After 10th attempt, its going to next kafka message. Where is the setting to change the 10 no.of times, how can we make to call unlimited no. of times until acknowledge method called?.
I'm aware of the options like "FixedBackOff" or "ExponentialBackOff", but we dont want to add any such in the code, instead should be handled with "acknowledge" and "nack".
Please let me know if any more details required. Thanks

If you use acknowledgement.nack(), then you don't need to re-throw that exception back to the listener container. The logic there is like this:
            doInvokeRecordListener(cRecord, iterator);
            if (this.commonRecordInterceptor !=  null) {
                this.commonRecordInterceptor.afterRecord(cRecord, this.consumer);
            }
            if (this.nackSleepDurationMillis >= 0) {
                handleNack(records, cRecord);
                break;
            }

So, if you throw an exception from your @KafkaListener, then handleNack() is not going to happen.
The nack is like a retry, but involving the Broker with its seek capabilities on the topic:
/**
 * Negatively acknowledge the current record - discard remaining records from the poll
 * and re-seek all partitions so that this record will be redelivered after the sleep
 * duration. This will pause reading for the entire message listener for the specified
 * sleep duration and is not limited to a single partition.
 * Must be called on the consumer thread.
 * <p>
 * @param sleep the duration to sleep; the actual sleep time will be larger of this value
 * and the container's {@code maxPollInterval}, which defaults to 5 seconds.
 * @since 2.8.7
 */
default void nack(Duration sleep) {

If you don't want re-seeking, but rather in-memory retry, then you don't need to involve that acknowledgement, but rather throw an exception and configure DefaultErrorHandler for respective BackOff, e.g. FixedBackOff.UNLIMITED_ATTEMPTS.
UPDATE
Here is a simple application which does forever retry for the same record:
spring.application.name=so-78784779
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=manual
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=my_consumer_group
spring.kafka.template.default-topic=TEST_TOPIC


@SpringBootApplication
public class So78784779Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So78784779Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "TEST_TOPIC")
    public void myKafkaListener(String data, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        System.out.println("DATA: " + data);
        acknowledgment.nack(Duration.ofMillis(10));
    }

}


@EmbeddedKafka
@SpringBootTest
class So78784779ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate<?, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Test
    void testApplication() throws InterruptedException {
        this.kafkaTemplate.sendDefault("data #1");
        this.kafkaTemplate.sendDefault("data #2");
        this.kafkaTemplate.flush();

        Thread.sleep(120_000);
    }

}

And I see in the console output only DATA: data #1. Much more times than 10. I'm not sure what are those seconds delay between consumes, but probably that's how consumer group works when we seek.

Thanks for the reply. But I have tried with both by throwing exception and not throwing it along with nack. In both the cases, its trying only for 10 times and incrementing to next offset. How can I resolve it? (would like to achieve unlimited with only nack and acknowledge).

See an UPDATE in my answer. Feels like we are not on the same page.

Thanks for the detailed update @Artem. The issue is resolved when I use "acknowledgment.nack(i,Duration.ofMillis(1000))", so far, using "acknowledgment.nack(Duration.ofMillis(1000))", but since we enabled batch mode, we need to provide the specific index of the message in the batch. Now I see its calling unlimited times. I see its working, but please correct if my understanding is incorrect.

That's correct, but batch story is something new here and might deserve its own StackOverflow question.
